# MongoDB and Minimongo sorting null and undefined differently

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor, minimongo

When sorting ascending in MongoDB, result is that null and undefined are first and then fields with value. When sorting ascending in Minimongo, result is that null is first, then fields with value and then undefined at the end. This difference is making problem. Is there a way to MongoDB and Minimongo sort the same way null and undefined? [image: Minimongo sorting]

Comment: whats the question here?

Comment: Is there a way to MongoDB and Minimongo sort the same way null and undefined?

Answer (score 0):

This is more an issue with [minimongo](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/minimongo), since MongoDB published the canonical [BSON type sort order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/) and has been using this type ordering for a long time.

Unfortunately minimongo hasn't been updated for more than a year.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute in the browser console:

```js
const test = new Mongo.Collection(null);
test.insert({foo: undefined});
test.insert({foo:'foo'});
test.insert({foo:null});
test.find({}, { sort: { foo: 1 } }).map(i => i.foo);
```

It correctly prints: `[undefined, null, 'foo']`. So please provide a reproduction.

Comment: Can you instead of 'foo' try use some MongoDB date?

Comment: I use miniMongoExplorer to see data.